# Обтекание блока float

Tags: css, html

Если взять за пример:

**HTML:**

```
   <div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="inf"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image {
float:left;
}

.inf {

}
```

то, текст, размещенный в `.inf`, невозможно выровнять по верхнему краю блока `.image`, `vertical-align:top` не срабатывает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/7xLkj2nt/

http://jsfiddle.net/t4Lxs220/

http://jsfiddle.net/g35vouwx/

Answer (score 1):

.inf {float:left;} тоже добавьте.